# SQL Update records from one table column using another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Im having trouble moving data from one table into another. The context is this:

I have two tables, Table A has a column which contains Guids and looks like this:

```
+---------+
|  ent_id |   
+---------+
|       1 | 
|       2 | 
|       3 | 
|       4 | 
|       5 | 
+---------+
```

Table B also has a column which contains a guid and looks like this:

```
+---------+
|party_id |  
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 | 
|       3 | 
|       4 | 
|       5 | 
+---------+
```

I need to update the records in Table A with the records in table B

To be more specific I tryed:

```
Update TableA
Set ent_id =  
(
   Select party_id from Table B
)
```

but this only updated each ent_id with one single repeating GUID from TableB

Comment: What sort of trouble are you having?

Comment: Whats are "guids"? Can you please provide some more explanation so we can help out.

Comment: I know that I could probably use a cursor to loop through each record and insert it in but this can take a while.. I was looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: GUID is a field that looks like a serial number

Comment: Huh?  Why not just truncate `TableA` and insert the values in from `TableB`?  I don't get what you are trying to do.  Furthermore, your example data has the before and after data being exactly the same, so nothing would need to be done.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff.. The sample data is just that.. a sample.. if they were unique guids i need to replace all the guids in table A with those in table B

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableA    
SET TableA.Field1=TableB.Field1,
TableA.Field2=TableB.Field2,
TableA.Field3=TableB.Field3,
TableA.Field4=TableB.Field4,
TableA.Field5=TableB.Field5
FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ent_id=TableB.party_id
```

Does this work?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Elena, I'm currently not at work but I will let you know if your solution worked tomorow.

Comment: What was the trouble you were having?

Comment: Just saw your edited answer.. This method may take a while since there could be up 50,000 records